# How to find Facebook group by keyword and its members

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to find Facebook group by keyword and its member. So how i can get it with keyword and minimum member?

> https://graph.facebook.com/search/?q=keyword&type=group&access_token=ACC_TOKEN

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only search for groups by name, as you can read in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#search

After getting the result of the call to the Search API, you can use this endpoint to get access to members: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group/members

...but that is only possible for groups you manage, with the `user_managed_groups` permission.

Comment: Thank u! But json in Fb Graph is limited <5.000 member, Next page is not working. How i can resolve it?

Comment: not sure why you even want to know, it only works for groups you manage. and if you want so SEARCH for groups, most likely you want to search for groups you do NOT manage.

Comment: `/group-id/members` only delivers about around 5,000 members, that is a known bug. (But from what FB devs have stated in the FB Developers Group so far, not one they intend on fixing any time soon.)